# Get value of enum type

Tags: java, enums

I have defined enum as following

```
   public enum JoinType {
    EQ("="), GTE(">="), GT(">"),
    LT("<"), LTE("<="), NEQ("!=");

    private String value;

    JoinType(String val) {
        val = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
 }
```

When using if JoinType joinType= EQ , I want to get "=" 
I tried using getValue() but it returns null. 
Does anyone know how to get it

Comment: Typo in your constructor.

Comment: The fact that the error is trivial, doesn't mean the question has to be downvoted. I'm upvoting it.

Answer (score 4):

You switched the values in the constructor. Should be:

```
JoinType(String val) {
    value = val;
}
```

Comment: If everything had been declared final as it ought to have been then this would have been a compilation error.

Comment: What do you mean? With `value` field declared as final it does compile.

Comment: [No it doesn't](https://ideone.com/Ba0N7M). The field is left uninitialized.

Comment: All right, I thought you meant that in regards to the answer and not the original code in question. You're right.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor should be

```
JoinType(String val) {
    this.value = val;
 }
```

Now you can do this

```
JoinType type = JoinType.EQ;
System.out.println(type.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the constructor you're assigning the property to the parameter instead of the other way round.